# What's the source of Mark Zuckerberg's lines in South Park S21E04 ("Franchise Prequel")

Tags: south-park

Season 21, Episode 4 of South Park features a character parodying Facebook CEO Mark Zuckerberg. The poor audio quality (and utter bizarreness, even for SP standards) of his voice lines seems to hint that they are not recorded by a voice actor in a proper studio like the other dialog of the show. I would presume that it's actually Zuckerberg's voice from an unrelated audio recording. Where are the lines from and what's the original context of Zuckerberg's statements?

Comment: Can't speak to your assertion that they are lifted lines, but the dialog itself is bog-standard anime fighting-style banter where they have monologues between every punch like Dragonbawlz, One Piece, etc etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I would presume that it's actually Zuckerberg's voice from an unrelated audio recording.

Nope, it's Trey Parker's voice. The low quality is deliberately applied to the recording. The lines are not from anything specifically, but evoke old-fashioned Kung Fu film dubbing.

---

> This Zuckerberg is delusional, rosy-cheeked, his voice out of sync, like a bad English dub. His catchphrase, “What’s your shtyle?” is a reference to that annoying guy from Enter the Dragon. He fights the members of the town using imaginary martial arts

-- [Dani Di Placido, Forbes](https://www.forbes.com/sites/danidiplacido/2017/10/13/south-park-review-franchise-prequel-swipes-at-mark-zuckerberg-misses)

> Zuck tells the town it cannot block his fighting style, and waves his arms while making sound effects like an old kung fu movie villain.

-- [Josh Constine, TechCrunch](https://techcrunch.com/2017/10/12/south-park-vs-zuckerberg/)